# How to make parametrizable properties in WPF user controls?

Tags: wpf, properties

I want to refactor many similar controls that only differ in the value of a single property (besides positioning properties).

Imagine that I have an user control (let's call it UC1) that have a `Label`. The `Label.Content` should be `value + ":"` where value is passed through a Property to the user control.

I could implement it by hand using the `Initialized` event, but it happens that in my case it isn't a `Label` but a custom control (let's call it UC2) which itself needs the property on its own `Initialized` event.

Somehow the UC2 `Initialized` runs before the UC1's, and it throws an exception because the property value is not set yet.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problem is cause by calling `InitializeComponent()` inside the user control when it shouldn't.

It may cause the `Initialized` event to be fired twice.